# CSS height as a variable and how to calculate 60% of total screen size

Tags: html, css

Using Bootstrap (and its Navbar) I have a jumbotron which starts at 30% from the top of the screen size. I did that using css: top=30%. In addition I have a Navbar which drops down a menu when mobile sized. The dropdown navbar menu should cover the jumbotron always (all screen sizes).

So mathematically the navbar dropdown size should be 30% of screensize + height in pixels of the jumbotron (lets say fixed for now, but might vary according to screen size...).

Currently I can adjust the height of the navbar dropdown menu using this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

However these are fixed values and I want them to be calculated as described as variables (preferably with a 'minimum total height' of the dropdown menu so it will never be too small).

I am new to bootstrap and UI design etc. So how should one do this?

Comment: Use `100vh` to get the window height

Comment: Maybe you could provide a jsfiddle for us to get a better visual of what you are talking about? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Tushar Yes, however that leaves two parts unsolved for me: 1. it is 30vh plus (e.g) 50px (jumbotron height); how do i do that? 2. when calculated how do I 'insert' it into the 'height:' field? Actually I would be another calculation using the lineheight of the number of lines in the dropdown menu...

Comment: @RononDex I know about fiddles, but the core of my question is quite simple: how do I put 100vh+50px in the height field of the navbar?

Comment: @musicformellons with [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `viewport height` CSS property for that and use the `calc()` function of CSS3 arithmetics like so:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    height: calc(30vh + 10px);
}
```